# Running Pytorch with torch.distributed.launch requires more memory?

Tags: pytorch

I can run my model with few GPUs perfectly (by few I mean anything less than 5). When I increased the number of GPUs, let's say 10, I got Cuda out of memory error:

```
RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 12.50 MiB (GPU 0; 10.92 GiB total capacity; 8.57 MiB already allocated; 9.28 GiB free; 4.68 MiB cached)
```

I used `torch.distributed.launch` and `DistributedDataParallel` to execute my script. I would like to know, what is the reason for this behavior and how can I avoid it? Does the master node require more memory? if so, how much it needs? How can I calculate it? How can I run my code with 10 GPUs?

Few things to consider:

- This issue happens on V100 GPUs as well
- reducing batch-size doesn't help since my batch size is already 1